# Series.isin(dataframe) not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am working on a project where I have to find the function name from my log.
To do this, I parsed all the strings in my log file to create a Series. I have a data frame which is having list of all function names.

I am using isin operator of Series so that if a particular string in my log is a function name, isin will return True at its index.

I have a string F4211FSEditLine at index 9 of my Series and F4211FSEditLine
is present in my dataframe.

Here is my code:

`es = pd.Series(words)
bsfn_1 = pd.read_excel('F9862.xlsx',index_col = None, parse_cols = [1])`

words is a list which I converted to a Series.
F9862 is an excel sheet which has all the function names in second column.

I tried the statement `es.isin(bsfn_1.loc[:'Function Name'])`
but it returns False for all elements.

If I try the following statement, I am getting answer True:

```
es[9] in bsfn_1.values
```

Can I use this method to identify if the list elements are present in my dataframe. If its wrong , could you please suggest me a better way.

I am expecting a True at index 9 when I do isin operation.

Thanks
Abin

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I tried using my column name, but still its all False.es.isin(bsfn_1.loc[:'Function Name']) returns False for all elements

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html. series.isin() takes list as a value. You need to provide snippet of your data to get this any further.

Comment: Is there an option to attach my files here, I am not aware of it.

Comment: The best way to get your issue resolved on SO is by providing of df.head() and expected output. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve